# Use of lang in search tag?

Tags: search

I came across below tags in EE during advance search..

Where do we define variables and what is the use of them??
What exactly is "lang" and where can I find in EE??

```
{lang:search_by_keyword}    
{lang:exact_phrase_match}
{lang:search_in_titles}
{lang:channels}
{lang:any_category}
```

Answer (score 1):

These tags are used in the EE search module. You can find [here](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/search/results.html) how to use them.